# How to access the object present i na public method of a class in another Java class

Tags: java, package

File 1: I have a public method which contain the declaration of a object.

File 2: I want to import this class and want to acess the object.

the object in file 1 is

```
public stamp1
{
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceTemplatePDFUrlStream);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
}
```

so how to acess it in file 2:

```
import file.*;
```

What to do here?

Comment: Could you try explaining that a bit more clearly

Comment: What do you mean *public method which contain the declaration of a object*? `public stamp1` - that's invalid syntax in Java. Could you please clean up your question and post what code you actually have?

Comment: You haven't shown any methods in file 1... Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2):

You should rethink your program if you have to do something as terrible as this.

This is what class variables are for. Declare `reader` and `stamper` as private variables then use getters to get it form outside your class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private PdfReader reader;
    private PdfStamper stamper;

    public void stamp1() {
        // ...
        reader = new PdfReader(sourceTemplatePDFUrlStream);
        stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
    }

    public PdfReader getReader() {
        return reader;
    }

    public PdfStamper getStamper() {
        return stamper;
    }
}
```

Comment: `public stamp1{}` won't compile.

Comment: Of course it won't :) I used the original examle for base. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. An object in a public method is a local variable, only available in that method while the method is executed.

A method can return such objects, then you can get it. Or the object is saved as attribute, then there might be a getter to get it, or it could be visible.